# Angular Universal BrowserModule.withServerTransition is deprecated, what is the replacement for this?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular16

I am using Angular 16.0.0 and with Angular Universal server side rendering, but when I
Import `BrowserModule.withServerTransition` in my app module its marked as deprecated, what is the replacement for it ?

[image]

my app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button'
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { CoursesCardListComponent } from './courses-card-list/courses-card-list.component';
import {CourseComponent} from "./course/course.component";
import { MatDatepickerModule } from "@angular/material/datepicker";
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { MatInputModule } from "@angular/material/input";
import { MatListModule } from "@angular/material/list";
import { MatPaginatorModule } from "@angular/material/paginator";
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from "@angular/material/progress-spinner";
import { MatSelectModule } from "@angular/material/select";
import { MatSidenavModule } from "@angular/material/sidenav";
import { MatSortModule } from "@angular/material/sort";
import { MatTableModule } from "@angular/material/table";
import { MatToolbarModule } from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import {CoursesService} from "./services/courses.service";
import {CourseResolver} from "./services/course.resolver";
import { CourseDialogComponent } from './course-dialog/course-dialog.component';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CourseComponent,
    CoursesCardListComponent,
    CourseDialogComponent,
    AboutComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    //BrowserTransferStateModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CoursesService,
    CourseResolver
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-universal-course",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "serve:prerender": "http-server -c-1 dist/angular-universal-course/browser",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run angular-universal-course:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/angular-universal-course/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --configuration production && ng run angular-universal-course:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run angular-universal-course:prerender  --routes routes.txt"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.15.0",
    "http-server": "^14.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need to set an ID use the `APP_ID` `InjectionToken` :

`{ provide: APP_ID,  useValue: 'serverApp' }`.

NB: If you bootstrap only one Angular app on your page, you can just remove it. Specifying is only necessary when you have multiple angular apps.